# PHP, PDO & MySQL - returned query order not correct

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-order-by

Example table layout:
http://rextester.com/QSDQA17146

I'm not 100% sure.. but I believe the error is stemming from the query side of things....

Background:
I have a query..that I pass an array to, to be used in retrieving data based on that value/field in the array from the table.

I was initially using an IN() clause.. but because my array can/does have duplicates (ie: 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 7).. I need a row returned for each value in the IN() clause (even though there is only 1 row in the table)..

After getting some help here..I was told to update this to a UNION ALL query.. so I could actually get a row returned for each item in my array (regardless if it was a duplicate or not)

```
SELECT * FROM tablex
WHERE CONCAT(brandname, ' ', dosage) IN (
    'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg',
    ' SEE NOTES BELOW',
    'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg'
) ORDER BY FIELD(
    CONCAT(brandname, ' ', dosage),
    'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg',
    ' SEE NOTES BELOW',
    'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg'
);
```

So I updated things best I could to use PDO and UNION ALL calls.

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT 1 as seq,
  'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg' as item
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ' SEE NOTES BELOW '
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg'
) AS inList
INNER JOIN pbaap_drugs AS t ON inList.item = CONCAT(t.brandname, ' ', t.dosage);
```

I now do get a row returned for each item.. however the returned data is NOT adhering to the original order of the array passed into the query.

I'm calling function/query like so:

```
$gn_displayList = get_displayList_alt($tablename, $conn, array_values(array_filter($_POST['gn_MedicineSelect'])));//array_filter() added to get count of only non empty indexes (no bloat)
```

I tried to output some DEBUG code and follow where/where the array order is changing.. and it seems to be in the query return portion?

Here is the array (parsed) when it is passed into the function above:

```
FILTERED ARRAY CONTENTS: array(3) { [0]=> string(39) "Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg" [1]=> string(17) " SEE NOTES BELOW " [2]=> string(39) "Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg" }
```

In the actual query function where I dynamically build the UNION ALL structure..etc..  I check the array again  (I can post this... but I dont want to deter from the focus on the order of things) ;)

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(39) "Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg" [1]=> string(17) " SEE NOTES BELOW " [2]=> string(39) "Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg" }
```

All seems well.. correct content.. and correct original order.

However.. when I get my query response/data.. the order is NOT the same.  It seems to have alpha sorted it?

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(2) "74" ["lastupdated"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["category"]=> string(24) "5-Lipoxygenase Inhibitor" ["brandname"]=> string(32) "Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet" ["genericname"]=> string(8) "zileuton" ["dosage"]=> string(6) "600 mg" ["image"]=> string(43) "Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg.jpg" ["zone"]=> string(16) "green,yellow,red" ["menu"]=> string(1) "1" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(2) "74" ["lastupdated"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["category"]=> string(24) "5-Lipoxygenase Inhibitor" ["brandname"]=> string(32) "Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet" ["genericname"]=> string(8) "zileuton" ["dosage"]=> string(6) "600 mg" ["image"]=> string(43) "Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg.jpg" ["zone"]=> string(16) "green,yellow,red" ["menu"]=> string(1) "1" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(2) "78" ["lastupdated"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["category"]=> string(0) "" ["brandname"]=> string(16) " SEE NOTES BELOW" ["genericname"]=> string(0) "" ["dosage"]=> string(0) "" ["image"]=> string(0) "" ["zone"]=> string(16) "green,yellow,red" ["menu"]=> string(1) "1" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

Comment: I corrected my typo on the original question, and told you to order by inList.seq; did that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an `ORDER BY` clause on a `SELECT`, MySQL is free to return rows in any sequence it chooses. This behavior conforms with the standard.

If we need rows returned in a particular order, we provide an `ORDER BY` on the outermost `SELECT`.

For example, we can list the `seq` column as the first expression in the `ORDER BY` so that rows will be returned in `seq` order. We can add additional expressions to the ORDER BY to make the order of the rows more deterministic (i.e. when there are multiple rows from `t` that "match" a row from `inList`)

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.lastupdated
     , t.category
     , t.brandname
     , t.genericname
     , t.dosage
     , t.image
     , t.zone
     , t.menu
     , t.active
  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS seq, 'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg' AS item 
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, ' SEE NOTES BELOW '
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg' 
       ) inList
  JOIN pbaap_drugs t
    ON CONCAT(t.brandname, ' ', t.dosage) = inList.item
 ORDER
    BY inList.seq
     , t.brandname
     , t.dosage
     , ...
```

(Note that rows from `t` that match `item` on rows with seq=1 and seq=3 are not going to match rows with seq=2. The specification isn't clear about what the expected return from the query, aside from the order of the rows.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The passed in array should be used as a 'look' for the brandname + dosage cols together.  It found it should return everything in that row.

Comment: Sorry I think this was missing from the original post..

But I do in fact have an ORDER BY FIELD() in use:

ORDER BY FIELD(
    CONCAT(brandname, ' ', dosage),
    'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg',
    ' SEE NOTES BELOW',
    'Zyflo CR Extended-release tablet 600 mg'


The part that I missing out on.. is why its NOT sticking to that order on the output?  it puts zyflo, zyflo see details. in that order instead of zyflo, see details, zyflo order.. (the same original order as the array passed into it has)

Comment: THANK YOU!  This has been killing me (and many other members) for days.  I couldn't get an answer (maybe my over explaining perhaps?)

But I believe with your updates.. it is NOW ordering correctly:

SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT 1 as seq, :item0 as item UNION ALL SELECT 2, :item1 UNION ALL SELECT 3, :item2 )AS inList JOIN pbaap_drugs AS t ON CONCAT(t.brandname, ' ', t.dosage) = inList.item ORDER BY inList.seq, t.brandname

Comment: @whispers Not that it would hurt anything, but since there is only one brand name per seq, ordering by brandname is redundant.